# XML ElementTree - indexing tags

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I have a XML file:

```
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:2">
   <text>It has great sushi and even better service.</text>
</sentence>
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:3">
   <text>The entire staff was extremely accomodating and tended to my every need.</text>
</sentence>
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:4">
   <text>I&apos;ve been to this restaurant over a dozen times with no complaints to date.</text>
</sentence>
```

Using XML ElementTree, I would like to insert a tag `<Opinion>` that has an attribute `category=`. Say I have a list of chars `list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, is it possible to incrementally asign them to each text so I have:

```
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:2">
   <text>It has great sushi and even better service.</text>
   <Opinion category='a' />
</sentence>
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:3">
   <text>The entire staff was extremely accomodating and tended to my every need.</text>
   <Opinion category='b' />
</sentence>
<sentence id="en_BlueRibbonSushi_478218345:4">
   <text>I&apos;ve been to this restaurant over a dozen times with no complaints to date.</text>
   <Opinion category='c' />
</sentence>
```

I am aware I can use the sentence id attribute but this would require a lot of restructuring of my code. Basically, I'd like to be able to index each sentence entry to align with my list index.

Comment: Attributes are a dictionary. Dictionary order is not guaranteed to be preserved in any way.

Comment: Oh I see. Works with the validator (checking against as a gold standard) as is so no need to change. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SubElement` factory function to add elements to the tree.
Assuming your XML data is in a variable called `data`, this will add the elements to your document tree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.XML(data)
for elem, category in zip(tree.findall('sentence'), ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    Opinion  = ET.SubElement(elem, 'Opinion')
    Opinion.set('category', category)

ET.dump(tree)  # prints the tree; tree.write('output.xml') is another option
```

Comment: `zip` will stop when the shortest iterable passed in runs out, so the slicing you suggest isn't needed (because it won't make any difference).  In any case, I'm assuming the OP has some more interesting way of generating the category list.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!